# NSTextView Insert Line Break

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nstextview

I have an NSTextView that I need to insert a line break in. The code looks like this:

```
NSString *myString = @"test"
[myTextView insertText:myString];

/**** INSERT LINE BREAK HERE ****/

[[myTextView textStorage] insertAttributedString:MY_ATTRIBUTED_STRING atIndex:myString.length];
```

Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can use the literal \n for a newline

```
NSString *myString = @"test\n"
[myTextView insertText:myString];
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm way late to the game here, but there's something that needs mentioning:

NSTextView is a subclass of NSResponder.  NSResponder declares but does not implement a method

```
-insertNewline:
```

NSTextView *does* implement that method.  That's the way to do it, not manually building a string with '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jason. Use \n. I KNOW it works for iPhone, so it should definitely work for Mac.

Also, you forgot a semicolon on the end of the first line ;)